# Setting multiple new atype/dtype/itype with LAMMPS fix bond/create

Tags: software, molecular-dynamics, lammps, software-assistance, openpathsampling

When creating a new bond in a LAMMPS simulation with the command fix/bond create it is likely new angles/dihedrals/impropers be need to be set. This can be done with the atype/dtype/itype arguments however, these arguments seem to only take one integer value. I have models where many types of angles or dihedrals could be created from the formation of one new bond. **How do you set multiple of these types at once, and specify which new angle/dihedral belongs to which type?**

Comment: +1. Nice first question! In case you were not yet aware, we also have a LAMMPS chat room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps

Comment: @Matt have you considered looking into LAMMPS official mailing list regarding the same issue?

Comment: I wonder what's happened with this question. Is it something that is answered on the LAMMPS official mailing list? Is it something that Matt has now asked there? Personally I think this site is better suited for Q/A than the older "mail list" concept.